# org.junit cannot be resolved Errors go on. however Adding jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I added my jar files and edited my pom.xml file but I am still getting "The import org.junit cannot be resolved" Error.I already downloaded for Java from here: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/
And I opened my jar and added to build path.What is the wrong?

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>15</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like the Junit dependencies in your POM file are incomplete.  You only have a dependency on the Jupiter engine, not on the APIs.  And you have declared it as a full dependency not a test scoped dependency.

I suggest you look at the Junit 5 example for Maven; e.h. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.7.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven

It shows how to use the Junit "BOM" dependency, which will import all of the other Junit dependencies required.  Like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Show us the code that is giving this compilation error.  And provide more of the build output showing the context.  And tell us how you are building ... or running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath".
Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars.
Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath".
```

This is solved my problem

Comment: OK ... so you shouldn't need to do this kind of thing.  Use Eclipse's Maven plugin (properly) and it will take care of setting up the classpath / buildpath based on what the POM file says about the dependencies.  It strikes me that you need to spend some time reading up on how Maven works, and on how Maven / Eclipse integration works.